# Object As Interface

Tags: c#, object, interface, casting, type-conversion

I've got an object that implements an interface, I then find that object using reflection. How can I cast the object into the interface and then place it into a `List<IInterface>` ?

Comment: Post some code and point to where you are stuck.

Comment: oh irony: the question title **is the answer** exactly

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You do not need to cast the object if it's of a type that implements the interface.

```
IMyBehaviour subject = myObject;
```

If the type of `myObject` is just `Object` then you need to cast. I would do it this way:

```
IMyBehaviour subject = myObject as IMyBehaviour;
```

If `myObject` does not implement the given interface you end up with `subject` being `null`. You will probably need to check for it before putting it into a list.

Answer (score 3):

```
public interface IFoo { }
public class Foo : IFoo {}

private SomeMethod(object obj)
{
    var list = new List<IFoo>();
    var foo = obj as IFoo;

    if (foo != null)
    {
        list.Add(foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or if you have a list foo of type Foo:  var list = new List<IFoo>(foo.ToArray());

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that

> cast[s] the object into the interface and then place it into a List

```
public void CastAndAdd(object objThatImplementsMyInterface, IList<IMyInterface> theList) 
{
    theList.Add((IMyInterface)objThatImplementsMyInterface);
}
```

I mean, if you've already found the object and have the list, this is quite elementary.  Just replace `IMyInterface` with whatever interface you're using.

Or generalize from this as appropriate for your specific code.